# A problem on limits

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

When is it the case that $\limsup _{n}(\alpha a_{n})=\alpha \limsup _{n} a_{n} ?$ When does it not hold?

I believe that this holds when $\alpha \geq$ 0, then the equality can be obtained. Are there any other conditions?

Comment: This is always the case for $\alpha >0$. Use the fact that the lim sup is the maximal subsequential limit of a sequence to get a fast proof.

Comment: For $\alpha >0$, @HennoBrandsma has already answered. I will only add that the following holds: $$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow +\infty} (- x_n) = - \liminf_{n \rightarrow +\infty} x_n $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This holds only if $\alpha \geq 0$, as the hint above mentions.

For $\alpha < 0$ this becomes false. For example,

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} (-1) (-1)^n = 1$$
$$-\limsup_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n = -1$$

Comment: Does the question only ask for conditions on $\alpha$?  I think it can just as legitimately be interpreted on conditions on $x_k$.  If $\lim \sup x_n = 0$ then $\alpha =0$ is fine and if $x_k = 0$ then any $\alpha$ is fine.  Of course if any $x_m\ne 0$ and $\alpha < 0$ this is impossible.